# About "INSERT INTO... VALUES", Error message : VALUES clause must contain at least one element

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm trying to set up a small attendance database for a project. One of the tables has three columns, 2 INTs and 1 SMALLINT. 
What I'm trying to do is insert these values into the table but I'm running into an error (provided under the code)
I think I should note that I'm using NetBean's Derby 
 Here's the code I'm using

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_PRESENCE(STUDENT_ID, CLASS_SCHEDULE_ID, PRESENT)
 VALUES (201610814, 101, 1), 
        (20166884, 101, 0),
        (201610814, , 102, 1),
        (20166884, 102, 1);
```

The error message I get:

`[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X80] VALUES clause must contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed.`

I tried engulfing the 4 "input brackets" into one big bracket for `VALUES`, but that also didn't work. Any guidance would be appreciated, I'm still quite new to this. Thank you

EDIT: Thank you guys so much. I feel like such a dumbass, I've been staring at this for about an hour and I have no idea how I missed that.. Thank you!!

Comment: You put an extra comma in it by mistake : (201610814, , 102, 1) <-- delete the comma

Comment: indeed this question seams to be a simple typographical error.. Also the error seams [not](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oQHDML94xnJkiQANntJkc5/0) to be MySQL related.

Comment: Ah man, thank you so much. I've been staring at this for so long I don't know how I missed it. Thank you guys so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by Beatrice and Raymond Nijland, you've placed an extra comma (,) in your query.

Remove the extra comma at `(201610814, , 102, 1),`